# ASP.NET MVC User is in all roles

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize

In ASP.NET you can decorate a method as such

```
[Authorize(Roles="Moderator,Tester")]
Function ActionResult Foo()
{
   return View();
}
```

This will limit access to users that are in one of the roles specified.

I have a requirement where the user must be in all the roles specified.  I can create a new role for this; But I was wondering if it is possible to decorate the method such, that the user must be part of all the roles specified?

Is this possible using the `Authorise` attribute or will I need to create my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use The `[Authorize]` attribute multiple times:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Moderator")]
[Authorize(Roles="Tester")]
Function ActionResult Foo()
{
   return View();
}
```

This will require the user to be in both (or more) roles.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks.